# Different versions of postgres on the same port

Tags: database-connection, psql

How to connect to specific postgres version through psql when both (9.0 and 9.2) are on the same port? It's on RedHat 4.1.2.

Comment: In TCP/IP only one application can bind to a port at any one time, so you probably don't have two versions of an application running on the same port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run two versions of PostgreSQL on the same port by having them bind to different IP addresses.

Assign multiple IP addresses to a network interface, or add an extra network interface. Say `10.1.1.2` and `10.1.1.3`.

In your 9.1 install's `postgresql.conf` set your `listen_addresses` to one of the addresses; say `10.1.1.2`. In the 9.3 install's `postgresql.conf` set `listen_addresses` to bind to `10.1.1.3`. Restart both servers.

You might want to put `127.0.0.1` in the 9.3 server's `listen_addresses` so it binds to the local loopback address too. (Note that you can alias the loopback to add more IPs for the local host if you need to, e.g. `127.0.0.2`).

If using separate IPs is not going to work for you, your only other option is to use a *container* that provides virtually isolated network stacks (like LXC), or use full virtualisation.